# Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql

Hey everyone I have been having a problem with my SQL database, specifically the foreign key. Here is the table I am trying to enter into.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL Primary Key,
    LastName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    City varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    State char(2) NOT NULL,
    TelephoneAreacode char(5) NOT NULL,
    TelephoneNumber char(8) NOT NULL,
    JobTitle varchar(30) NOT NULL    Foreign Key References Job_Title(JobTitle),
    EEO1Classification varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    HireDate char (10) NOT NULL,
    Salary money NOT NULL,
    Gender varchar(7) NOT NULL,
    Age int NOT NULL
)
```

And the data

```
INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES ('95687', 'Edelman', 'Glenn', '175 Bishops Lane', 'LA Jolla', 'CA', '619', '5550199','Cashier',  'Sales Workers', '10/7/2003', '$21,500', 'Male', '64'),
    ('95688', 'McMullen', 'Eric', '763 Church ST', 'Lemm Grove', 'CA', '619', '5550135','Bagger',  'Sales Workers', '11/1/2002', '$12,500', 'Male', '20'),
    ('95995', 'Slentz', 'Raj', '123 Torrey DR', 'North Clairmont', 'CA', '619', '5550123','Assistant Manager',  'Officials & Managers', '6/1/2000', '$48,000', 'Male', '34'),
    ('55978', 'Broun', 'Erin', '2045 Parkway - Apt2B', 'Encinitas', 'CA', '760', '5550100', 'Bagger','Sales Workers', '3/12/2003', '$10,530', 'Female', '24'),
    ('55928', 'Carpenter', 'Donald', '927 Second St', 'Encinitas', 'CA', '760','5550154', 'Stocker','Office/Clerical', '11/1/2003', '$15,000', 'Male', '18'),
    ('59852', 'Esquivez', 'David', '10983 N. Coast Hwy Apt 902', 'Encinitas', 'CA', '760', '5550108','Butchers & Seafood Specialists',  'Operatives (Semi skilled)', '8/1/2003', '$19,000', 'Male', '22'),
    ('52362', 'Sharp', 'Nancy', '10793 Montecino RD', 'Ramona', 'CA', '858', '5550135', 'Cashier','Sales Workers', '7/12/2003', '$21,000', 'Female', '24');
```

The table with the foreign key is this one,

```
CREATE TABLE Job_Title (
    JobTitle varchar(30) NOT NULL Primary key,
    EEO1Classification varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    JobDescription varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    ExemptNonExempt varchar(30) NOT NULL,
)
```

And the data already entered there is

```
INSERT INTO Job_Title
VALUES 
     ('Accounting Clerk','Office/Clerical', 'Records Data', 'Non-Exempt'),
     ('Assistant Manager','Officials & Managers', 'Supervises and coordinates activities', 'Exempt'),
     ('Bagger','Sales Workers', 'Places customer orders in bags', 'Non-Exempt'),
     ('Cashier','Sales Workers', 'Operates cash register to itemize and total customer’s purchases', 'Non-Exempt'),
     ('Computer Support Specialist','Technician', 'Installs, modifies, and makes minor repairs to personal computers', 'Non-Exempt'),
     ('Dir. of Fin. & Acct.','Officials & Managers', 'Plans and directs the finance and accounting activities', 'Exempt'),
     ('Asst. - Bakery & Pastry','Craft Workers (Skilled)', 'Bakes Cakes and Pastries',  'Non-Exempt'),
     ('Butchers & Seafood Specialists','Operatives (Semi skilled)', 'Cuts Meat and seafood',  'Non-Exempt'),
     ('Stocker','Office/Clerical',  'Stocks Shelves',  'Non-Exempt');
```

Please help.

Comment: It helps to format the code so it is readable - also whati s the error and what exactly are you doing at the time

Comment: The error message is: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Employee__JobTit__09DE7BCC". The conflict occurred in database "KudlerFineFoodsEmployment", table "dbo.Job_Title", column 'JobTitle'.

Comment: I receive it when I try and enter data into the employee table which has the foreign key on the JobTitle column which links to the JobTitle Column in the Job_title Table.

Comment: Just ran your sql without errors.  Are you sure the Job_Title table has the rows you expect?

Comment: I have double and triple checked everything and I am pretty sure everything needed by the foreign key is in the primary key in the referenced table

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I do have a suggestion; eliminate all unnecessary columns and rows.  The goal being either to solve your problem yourself, or to make it easier for others to help you.  Nothing except the primary key is relevant for the job_title table for instance.  My gut feeling is that somewhere you are mixng up the title and the classification.  Also why is the classification in both tables?

Comment: Try the INSERT's one at a time.  See which ones gives the error.  Something is wrong with the data you copied above.   Once you/we know which job title is not inserting, it should be easier to determine the error...

Comment: Sparky I was just about to do that it seemed like the most logical thing for me to do at the current time, I will report back.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, it turns out I never entered the data into the secondary table because of a typo, so the foreign key never had any data to link to in the secondary table, again thanks for the great ideas and help.

Comment: There's also no Sales Workers entry in the job title listing in your question. Furthermore, I'd use IDs if I were you, rather than just text strings to make up the relationship. It'll be faster.

Comment: Another thing is NEVER do an insert without specifying the column names. This could have been a  problem where the column order was off and you were trying to put something other than the title in the title column.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the values you are inserting in the table that contains the foreign key ( child table ) has a corresponding value in the table that contains the primary key (parent Table )
i,e you can not insert something into the child table that has no corresponding  value in the parent table due to the pk -Fk relation ship

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the error occurs due to the reason that the Child table does not have the corresponding values already present in the Parent table's column which is being referenced as the foreign key. To do:

1. Truncating both the tables (make sure to backup the data if its
   bulky) could simply fix the problem.
2. Try entering values in the Child table that are existing already in
   the Parent table's column. Hope this would help.